# htlatex: method to set fraction of textwidth as minipage width not compatible with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

I am using the `make4ht` configuration from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591156/110602) to extract width as a fraction of textwidth from LaTeX code and add it to the CSS file. The configuration works as expected until I add a TikZ picture anywhere in the document. The MWE from [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/591066/110602) compiles correctly, but the following code generates an error (the error is there even if we delete the minipages entirely from the code below, I just left them in there to make sure any solutions proposed keep the minipage widths intact):

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode
    \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi 
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \noindent Text before.\medskip
    
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1.0\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \blindtext
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \blindtext  
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{center}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
            \node [draw, text width=1.3cm,  text centered] (s) {system $y=u$};
            \draw [->]  node[coordinate,left=1cm of s](u){} (u) -- node [above, near start] {$u$} (s);
            \draw [->] (s)  node[coordinate,right=1cm of s](y){} -- node [above, near end] {$y$} (y); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    21       Argument of \striptextwidth has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    21       Paragraph ended before \striptextwidth was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    21       Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    21       Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    21       Missing ) inserted for expression.
```

Any ideas on what the conflict is and how to fix it?

UPDATE: If I remove the `text width = 1.3cm` option from the node above, the error disappears and everything works as expected, but for some figures, I need multi line node text, so I need to restrict the text width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by the `minipage` configuration in TeX4ht configuration file that I provided in my previous answer. It expects that `minipage` width is specified as a fraction of `\textwidth`. It was OK, as you used this format in your previous `mwe`. The problem is when `minipage` you don't provide width in relation to `\textwidth`, which happens when you use TikZ `text width` option.

To fix that, we need to do a better calculation of width. Fortunately, thanks to LaTeX 3, we can now easily do floating-point calculations, which simplifies the configuration file and fixes your issue.

Here is the updated `cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\makeatletter

% we must refer to minipage from the css file, because tags are beeing
% written before we know dimensions
\newcount\mini@count
\ExplSyntaxOn
% save original minipage
\let\oldiimini\@iiiminipage
% redefine minipage
\def\@iiiminipage#1#2[#3]#4{%
  % calculate minipage dimensions and save it to the CSS file
  \Css{\#minipage\the\mini@count{width:\fp_eval:n{#4/\textwidth*100}\%;}}%
  \global\advance\mini@count by 1\relax%
  \oldiimini{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\ConfigureEnv{minipage}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="minipage" align="center" id="minipage\the\mini@count" style="border:1px solid black;">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>\Hnewline}%
% we must write dimension here to the css file
}{}{}

\makeatother

\Css{div.minipage {
 float: left; 
 } 
}

\Css{div.minipage:last-child {
 clear: none; 
 float: right; 
 }
}

\Css{ div.minipage + :not(.minipage) {clear:both;overflow:auto;width:100\%;}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Minipage width is now written to the CSS file using the following code:

```
\Css{\#minipage\the\mini@count{width:\fp_eval:n{#4/\textwidth*100}\%;}}%
```

The `#4` argument contains the width that is passed to minipage environment. It is then divided by `\textwidth` and multiplied by 100, to get the dimension in percents.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but a workaround. Everything works as expected if we use a `\parbox` inside the node text to set the text width instead of the `text width` option. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode
    \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi 
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \noindent Text before.\medskip
    
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1.0\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \blindtext
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \blindtext  
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{center}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
            \node [draw] (s) {\parbox[t]{1.3cm}{\centering system $y=u$}};
            \draw [->]  node[coordinate,left=1cm of s](u){} (u) -- node [above, near start] {$u$} (s);
            \draw [->] (s)  node[coordinate,right=1cm of s](y){} -- node [above, near end] {$y$} (y); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

compiles just fine with the config file [from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229935/110602):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
% to strip fraction from \textwidth
\def\striptextwidth#1\textwidth{#1}
% we must refer to minipage from the css file, because tags are beeing
% written before we know dimensions
\newcount\mini@count
% save original minipage
\let\oldiimini\@iiiminipage
% redefine minipage
\def\@iiiminipage#1#2[#3]#4{%
% calculate dimensions and save it to macro
\edef\miniwidth{\strip@pt\dimexpr(\striptextwidth#4pt)*100\relax\%}
\Css{\#minipage\the\mini@count{width:\miniwidth;}}%
\oldiimini{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}
}

\ConfigureEnv{minipage}{\advance\mini@count by 1\relax\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="minipage" align="center" id="minipage\the\mini@count" style="border:1px solid black;">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>\Hnewline}%
% we must write dimension here to the css file
}{}{}
\makeatother
\Css{div.minipage {
 float: left; 
 }
}
\Css{div.minipage:last-child {
 clear: none;
 float: right;
 }
}
\Css{ div.minipage + :not(.minipage) {clear:both;overflow:auto;width:100\%;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Not quite an answer, because it involves changing existing LaTeX code.